# update Timestamp Cell in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have An Sqlite Database and I have an extra cell in it with a Timestamp item. The timestamp should display the last operation done with the row.
(Z.B. has been updated) so everytime The row changes I want the timestamp to become the current timestamp. Especially when I query the row. 
In general I would now create a timestamp object and then update my row with the new timestamp.

But since this seems like a common operation which I think a lot of people have done I wonder If there is an other solution to register the last call of an object in a database. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a trigger whenever you update the row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_table_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON your_table_name
BEGIN
      update your_table_name SET updated_on = datetime('now') WHERE column_name = NEW.column_name;
END;
```

You can read about it a bit more here:

[CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Comment: thanks this seems like what I want to do! But since I am quite the biginner can you tell me where I put this conde? When I create the Table right? I am using a Database Handler so is there a function to to this or do I use the execSQL methode and build the string myself like you showed?

Comment: Yes, you can just use execSQL with the creation String.

Comment: Is this also possible for the get methode. Meaning when I take the crud operations and call the get(id) methode (not the get() (all items))

Comment: When ever I get one object from the database by the name I want to update the timestamp. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean after you do a select for example? if so, no. You can't use a Trigger afrer select afaik.